# React router is not working properly, trying to route some components but it's not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

My index.js is..

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM  from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

My App.js is ...

```
import React from "react";

import { BrowserRouter as Router,Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Join from "./components/Join";
import Chat from "./components/Chat";

const App = () => {
    return (
         <Router>
            <div>
         <Routes>
         <Route  path="/" exact component={Join} />
         <Route path="/chat"  component={Chat} /> 
         </Routes>
         </div>
         </Router>

);
    }

export default App;
```

I'm not able to find out the error, either App is not exporting properly or there's some issue on router or problem is with rendering. I don't know
and join component is

```
import React from "react";

const Join = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Hiii Join</h1> 
    )
}

export default Join;
```

Ideally it should display Hii Join but browser is blank.

Comment: Are you using react-router-dom@5.x.x? may be it transfer component as JSX ` <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />` check it : 
 https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5

Comment: Thanks for the help, issue solved using your code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code...

- package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.4",

}
```

- How did I define Route components?

```
import LoginScreen from './screens/login';
import RegisterScreen from './screens/register';
import HomeScreen from './screens/Home';

const Navigations = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen/>}/>
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen/>}/>
            <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterScreen/>}/>
            <Route path="/password" element={<PasswordScreen/>}/>
            <Route path="/types" element={<TypesScreen/>}/>
            <Route path="/status" element={<StatusScreen/>}/>
            <Route path="/test" element={<TestScreen/>} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundScreen/>}/>
        </Routes>
    )
}
```